# What is this cylindrical 4-pin connector called?

Tags: identification, connector, waterproof

What is the connector — specifically the one on the left — called?

[image: Unknown 4-pin connector]

UPDATE: Several folks below mentioned it might be a M16 4-Pin IP68 connector. There is a difference though between the shape of the notch on a M16 and the connector in question. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Where did that image come from? Maybe Bulgin.

Comment: It came from [here](https://nettigo.eu/products/waterproof-ip65-4-pin-connector-cable-200mm), but the item description is not very informative. It simply states "Waterproof (IP65) 4 pin connector". I need to make a custom cable/connector that connects USB-C to the male plug on the right, but first want to see if such a thing doesn't maybe already exist.

Comment: Mfg is "YCZX". Looks like M16 cylindrical waterproof connectors, but not quite standard.

Comment: @TEMLIB Thanks, this is helpful.

Comment: Manufacturer may be YETOR.

Comment: The keyword most often associated with this style of connector is "DIN".  Maybe search for that along with "weatherproof" or "waterproof".  Take a look at "M16 4 pin IP68"

Comment: Search for 4-pin Power DIN connectors.

Comment: Also please note that anyone trying to sell you a "IP68 connector" is likely a scammer. The only thing IP68 means is custom underwater use below 1 meter - IP68 is a custom IP class which has to be defined from case to case. Furthermore IP68 does not mean that it can withstand IPx6 powerful water jets (or IPx9 high pressure water jets). Serious vendors will claim IP66/IP67 or such. Unless it's some scuba diving equipment, then it's probably IP68...

Comment: M16 means the shroud has an M16 thread. Your M16 picture appears to have a DIN alignment slot. Your original may not have a metric thread, but it is probably M16. It is not DIN: there may be an ISO standard, or it may be a private standard. The area I've had contact with (High Current DC), is almost entirely private standards, with no public standard for High Current electrical compatibility (import for safety regulations)

Comment: Also, the DIN/ISO connector is A code. A is the most common connector pair code. If there was a coding ridge on your large flat surface, it would be D-code, but I don't see that in your pictures.

Answer (score 1):

My Identiconn utility identifies it as a [Wesiri "big size" LED circular connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=led_lighting_circ_conn&s=big%20size). There are [sold on AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32993600651.html)